# Invert simple UIView mask (cut hole instead of clip to circle)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mask

I'm trying to avoid `CAShapeLayer` because I would need to mess with `CABasicAnimation`, not `UIView.animate`. So instead, I'm just using UIView's [`mask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622557-mask) property to mask views. Here's my code currently:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 300))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "TestImage")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        
        let maskView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 80, height: 80))
        maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue /// ensure opaque
        maskView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        imageView.mask = maskView /// set the mask
    }
}
```

| Without `imageView.mask = maskView` | *With* `imageView.mask = maskView` |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>[image]</kbd> | <kbd>[image]</kbd> |

It makes a portion of the image view visible. However, this is what I want:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Instead of making part of the image view visible, how can I cut a hole in it?

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to do? Animate the mask to be a different shape/size?

Comment: Yeah, to a different frame.

Comment: What did I tell you before? Everything in a mask depends on the transparency of its pixels. Yours are backwards. If you want a hole, it is the rounded rect that needs to be transparent and the rest needs to be opaque.

Comment: Moreover, layers can be animated — in fact, all animation _is_ layer animation ultimately — so your reason for not using layer masking is meaningless. However, that has nothing to do with the question. :)

Comment: @matt yeah I remember that. But how would I make edges opaque, but not the inner part? If I set the backgroundColor of the larger view to `.blue`, then a subview in the middle with a backgroundColor of `.clear` wouldn't have an effect...

Comment: Ah yes. So the subview technique will not work so readily here. But you see, you've changed the conditions of the problem, haven't you? Nevertheless, what I said about _how a mask works_ remains the same.

Comment: Note that there are _lots_ of answers to this kind of question; just search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+mask+hole

Comment: I wrote a sample project that demonstrates how to use a CAShapeLayer and a CABasicAnimation to animate the frame of your "window" through the image view. See my answer for the link, as well as a short GIF of the results. You should be able to use it as the starting point for your use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an image view and set that as your mask. Note that this does not lend itself to animation. If you want to animate the mask to different shapes, you should add a mask to your view's CALayer and use CALayerAnimation, as you mention. It's not that bad.

Below I outline how to generate an image with a transparent part (a hole) that you can use as a mask in an image view. If your goal is to animate the size, shape, or position of the hole, however, this won't work. You'd have to regenerate the mask image for every frame, which would be really slow.

Here's how you would get the effect your are after for static views using an image view as a mask:

Use <s>`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`</s> `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` to create an image that is opaque for most of your image, and has a transparent "hole" where you want a hole.

Then install that image in your image view, and make that image view your mask.

The code to create a mostly opaque image with a transparent rounded rect "hole" might look like this:

```
/**
 Function to create a UIImage that is mostly opaque, with a transparent rounded rect "knockout" in it. Such an image might be used ask a mask
 for another view, where the transparent "knockout" appears as a hole in the view that is being masked.
    - Parameter size:  The size of the image to create
    - Parameter transparentRect: The (rounded )rectangle to make transparent in the middle of the image.
    - Parameter cornerRadius: The corner radius ot use in the transparent rectangle. Pass 0 to make the rectangle square-cornered.
 */
func imageWithTransparentRoundedRect(size: CGSize, transparentRect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
    let image = renderer.image { (context) in
        let frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        context.fill(frame)
        let roundedRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: transparentRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        context.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
        context.cgContext.setBlendMode(.clear)

        roundedRect.fill()
    }
    return image
}
```

And a `viewDidLoad` method that installs a UIImageView with a mask image view with a hole in it might look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .cyan
        let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)
        let origin = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
        let frame =  CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "TestImage")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2

        //Create a mask image view the same size as the (image) view we will be masking
        let maskView = UIImageView(frame: imageView.bounds)

        //Build an opaque UIImage with a transparent "knockout" rounded rect inside it.
        let transparentRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 80, height: 80)
        let maskImage = imageWithTransparentRoundedRect(size: size, transparentRect: transparentRect, cornerRadius: 20)

        //Install the image with the "hole" into the mask image view
        maskView.image = maskImage

        //Make the maskView the ImageView's mask
        imageView.mask = maskView /// set the mask
    }
}
```

I created a sample project using the code above. You can download it from Github here:

https://github.com/DuncanMC/UIImageMask.git

I just updated the project to also show how to do the same thing using a CAShapeLayer as a mask on the image view's layer. Doing it that way, it's possible to animate changes to the mask layer's path.

The new version has a segmented control that lets you pick whether to mask the image view using a UIImage in the view's mask property, or via a CAShapeLayer used as a mask on the image view's layer.

For the CAShapeLayer version, the mask layer's path is a rectangle the size of the whole image view, with a second, smaller rounded rectangle drawn inside it. The winding rule on the shape layer is then set to the "even/odd" rule, meaning that if you have to cross an even number of shape boundaries to get to a point, it is considered outside the shape. That enables you to create hollow shapes like we need here.

When you select the layer mask option, it enables an animation button that animates random changes to the "cutout" transparent rectangle in the mask.

The function that creates the mask path looks like this:

```
func maskPath(transparentRect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let fullRect = UIBezierPath(rect: maskLayer.frame)
    let roundedRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: transparentRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    fullRect.append(roundedRect)
    return fullRect
}
```

And the function that does the animation looks like this:

```
@IBAction func handleAnimateButton(_ sender: Any) {

    //Create a CABasicAnimation that will change the path of our maskLayer
    //Use the keypath "path". That tells the animation object what property we are animating
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")

    animation.autoreverses = true //Make the animation reverse back to the oringinal position once it's done

    //Use ease-in, ease-out timing, which looks smooth
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)

    animation.duration = 0.3 //Make each step in the animation last 0.3 seconds.


    let transparentRect: CGRect

    //Randomly either animate the transparent rect to a different shape or shift it
    if Bool.random() {
        //Make the transparent rect taller and skinnier
        transparentRect = self.transparentRect.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: -20, left: 20, bottom: -20, right: 20))
    } else {
        //Shift the transparent rect to by a random amount that still says inside the image view's bounds.
        transparentRect = self.transparentRect.offsetBy(dx: CGFloat.random(in: -100...20), dy: CGFloat.random(in: -100...100))
    }

    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: 0...30)
    //install the new path as the animation's `toValue`. If we dont specify a `fromValue` the animation will start from the current path.
    animation.toValue = maskPath(transparentRect: transparentRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath

    //add the animation to the maskLayer. Since the animation's `keyPath` is "path",
    //it will animate the layer's "path" property to the "toValue"
    maskLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    //Since we don't actually change the path on the mask layer, the mask will revert to it's original path once the animation completes.
}
```

The results (using my own sample image) look like this:
[image]

A sample of the CALayer based mask animation looks like this:

[image]

Comment: No one should be using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` any longer.

Comment: Good point. I slipped back into old ways. Off to edit my answer...

Comment: WOAH! Yo this is insane! This effort, though.. thanks so much!

Comment: I put an easter egg in the Github project that isn't in the GIF above. (Try the layer mask animation in the project.)